# Asp.net Auto Login to gmail

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, gmail

I have an intranet application, written in asp.net C#,

users enter the intranet, using their domain, sername and password, we use google applications and gmail for our company's email, I have a button that allow user connect to gmail URL, Users use same username and password for their gmail account, how can I write a code to auto login to gmail when their click this button, witout asking the username and password.

basically, auto login to their mail,

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You should use Gmail Agent API. This site contains the example of how you can use it..

http://johnvey.com/features/gmailapi/

this is the open source project on sourceforge

http://sourceforge.net/projects/gmail-api/

Regards.